# How to create a dataframe from a string key\tvalue delimited by '\t'

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a log file with the structure:

```
log_type    time_stamp  kvs
p   2019-06-05 18:53:20 us\tc\td\tus-xx-bb\th\ti-0b1\tvl\t20190605.1833\tvt\t20190605.1833\tvs\t20190508
p   2019-06-05 18:53:20 us\tc\td\tus-xx-bb\th\ti-03a\tvl\t20190605.1833\tvt\t20190605.1833
p   2019-06-05 18:53:20 us\tc\td\tus-xx-bb\th\ti-030
```

I need to read the kvs field, breaking the keys and turn into a seperate columns, the final DataFrame should look like this:

```
log_type    time_stamp us   d   h   vl  vt  vs
p   2019-06-05 18:53:20 c   us-xx-bb    0b1 20190605.1833   20190605.1833   20190508
p   2019-06-05 18:53:20 c   us-xx-bb    03a 20190605.1833   20190605.1833
p   2019-06-05 18:53:20 c   us-xx-bb    030
```

Very important, the number of keys in the kvs is dynamic and the name of the keys is also dynamic

kvs column is seperated by \t. If we split kvs column then even number element is header and odd number element is value.

An attempt would be to read the log file , create a dataframe with the schema based on all the strings and use write() function to transform the dataframe the HDFS file, but do not know how to do this

```
val logSchema = new StructType().add("log_type",StringType).add("time_stamp",StringType).add("kvs",StringType)
val logDF = spark.read.option("delimiter", "\t").format("com.databricks.spark.csv").schema(logSchema).load("/tmp/log.tsv")

I have also tried 
logDF.withColumn("pairkv", split($"kvs", "\t")).select(col("pairkv")(1) as "us" ,col("pairkv")(3) as "d" ,col("pairkv")(5) as "h" ,col("pairkv")(7) as "vl" ,col("pairkv")(9) as "vt" ,col("pairkv")(11) as "vs").show() 
But no luck
```

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution

```
logDF
.withColumn("us", regexp_extract(col("kvs") ,"(^|\\\\t)us\\\\t([\\w]+)",2))
.withColumn("d", regexp_extract(col("kvs") ,"(\\\\t)d\\\\t([\\w-]+)",2))
.withColumn("h", regexp_extract(col("kvs") ,"(\\\\t)h\\\\t([\\w-]+)",2))
.withColumn("vl", regexp_extract(col("kvs") ,"(\\\\t)vl\\\\t([\\w.]+)",2))
.withColumn("vt", regexp_extract(col("kvs") ,"(\\\\t)vt\\\\t([\\w.]+)",2))
.withColumn("vs", regexp_extract(col("kvs") ,"(\\\\t)vs\\\\t([\\w]+)",2))
.show()
```

In this way we have separate columns in DF

Answer (score 0):

In scala, it can be done as follows:

```
object DataFrames {

    case class Person(ID:Int, name:String, age:Int, numFriends:Int)
    def mapper(line:String): Person = {
      val fields = line.split(',')  

      val person:Person = Person(fields(0).toInt, fields(1), fields(2).toInt, fields(3).toInt)
      return person
    }

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        ....
        import spark.implicits._
        val lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("../myfile.csv")
        val people = lines.map(mapper).toDS().cache()
        ....
        //here people will be the dataframe...and you can execute your sql queries on this
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that you have 2 delimiter characters, `' '` and '\t'.

I can see one straight forward solution which is to reformat the input file in order to have only one separator character.

```
with open('original_log_file.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('new_lof_file.txt','w') as out:
        for line in f:
            out.write(line.replace(' ','\t')) #all separators are '\t'

df = pd.read_csv('new_lof_file.txt', delimiter ='\t)
#then fix the header and you are done.
```

An alternative approach would be to parse each line of the file, make a DataFrame out of it and then append it to the original DataFrame.

Here an example:

```
file = '''
p   2019-06-05 18:53:20 us\tc\td\tus-xx-bb\th\ti-0b1\tvl\t20190605.1833\tvt\t20190605.1833\tvs\t20190508
p   2019-06-05 18:53:20 us\tc\td\tus-xx-bb\th\ti-03a\tvl\t20190605.1833\tvt\t20190605.1833
p   2019-06-05 18:53:20 us\tc\td\tus-xx-bb\th\ti-030
'''

columns=['log_type', 'date', 'time', 'us', 'd', 'h', 'vl', 'vt', 'vs']
df = pd.DataFrame({k:[] for k in columns}) #initial df

for line in file.split('\n'):
    if len(line):
        clean_line = line.strip().replace('   ','\t').replace(' ','\t').split('\t') #fix the line
        #remove redundant header
        for c in columns:
            if c in clean_line:
                clean_line.remove(c)
        clean_line = [[x] for x in clean_line]
        df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(dict(zip(columns,clean_line))),'sort=True')

df = df[columns]
df.head()
```

Comment: Your solution is good but not possible in PROD environment. The log file is big in size and this is streaming data and there will be extra overhead in spark streaming job to create clone of log file

Comment: The overhead to do a `replace()` is nothing. Assuming that you don't want to rewrite the file, you still need to do `replace()` for each line and then you can pass it to a pandas dataframe. I will write a snippet.

Comment: I have also tried 
logDF.withColumn("pairkv", split($"kvs", "\t")).select(col("pairkv")(1) as "us" ,col("pairkv")(3) as "d" ,col("pairkv")(5) as "h" ,col("pairkv")(7) as "vl" ,col("pairkv")(9) as "vt" ,col("pairkv")(11) as "vs").show()

But no luck

Comment: @ManishSarafBhardwaj I have added the code to fix your lines on the fly.